# Error in 2nd ViewController Invalid redeclaration of 'doneAccessory'

Tags: ios, xcode10, swift5

Below my question is the code i'm using in xCode 10 to place a "Done" button on the pop up keyboard.
I have a second ViewController but don't know how to use this code on this second one. The errors displayed in my second ViewController are:

> Invalid redeclaration of 'doneAccessory'
>      Invalid redeclaration of 'addDoneButtonOnKeyboard()'
>      Invalid redeclaration of 'doneButtonAction()'

```
extension UITextField{

    @IBInspectable var doneAccessory: Bool{
        get{
            return self.doneAccessory
        }
        set (hasDone) {
            if hasDone{
                addDoneButtonOnKeyboard()
            }
        }
    }

    func addDoneButtonOnKeyboard()
    {
        let doneToolbar: UIToolbar = UIToolbar(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 50))
        doneToolbar.barStyle = .default

        let flexSpace = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
        let done: UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .done, target: self, action: #selector(self.doneButtonAction))

        let items = [flexSpace, done]
        doneToolbar.items = items
        doneToolbar.sizeToFit()

        self.inputAccessoryView = doneToolbar
    }

    @objc func doneButtonAction()
    {
        self.resignFirstResponder()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add this UITexfield extension to your helper class. Its good practice having all your extensions in the helper class.

You need not set anything about your second view controller. You need to open your storyboard and select the text field where you want the done button. Find the image to set the done button then you will not face any issue.

[image: Storyboard settings]

Comment: @EzeBuilt please let me know if this will solve your issue thanks.

Comment: Thanks for that, I should’ve picked up on that. sometimes the obvious is so obvious that you miss it altogether.

Comment: Agree @EzeBuilt. Cheers :D

Comment: However I am not sure why it won’t work on a TextView though.

Comment: @EzeBuilt Please create an extension for UITextView. & use it in the same way you have done for the text field. I am sure it will work.

Comment: Scrap my last comment, fixed now - just duplicated the code for TextView as well as TextField

Comment: Cool...Cheers @EzeBuilt. (y)

Comment: Glad to help, if this answer solved your problem please mark it as accepted by clicking the checkmark next to the answer. see: [How does accept an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) for more information. @EzeBuilt